# Reading from a continuously changing logfile

Tags: command-line, logs, tail, watch

There is `/location/of/thefile`, which is a continuously changing logfile. The average density of refreshes is 4 per minute, the possible maximal refresh rate could be 30-40 per minute. Every refresh adds 2-5 lines (average), but it could be hundreds in extreme cases. Every line begins with a `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]` timestamp followed by plaintext (100-200, max. a few hundred characters).

My task is to construct a **simple command** which continuously watches this logfile, and sends to the stdout every lines that contain the `foo` *OR* `bar` alphabetical strings. Before and after those (sub)strings there could be any characters (`\n` only after the (sub)string, of course), even `\0`. The capitalization of the words could be all of the possible variations.

Well, my ideas for the solution always contain syscalls for the timing, but I shouldn't use them. Please construct me a **simple command**. Thanks a very lot!

Comment: This is often called “tailing”, from [`tail -f`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/reading-from-a-continuously-changing-logfile/10837#10837). See [tag:tail] for other related questions, where you'll find fancier programs that can filter and color log lines.

Answer (score 30):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but is there a reason you can't use this?

`tail -f /location/of/thefile | grep -i -E "foo|bar"`

Comment: Does piping the output of `tail -f` to `grep` really work like that? If so, I'm going to have to start using that myself! For a case like this I would have suggested a `watch` command, but if this does indeed work it's so much better!

Comment: @Kromey: how would you expect it to work?

Comment: `tail -f` just continually streams output to stdout, right? I'd always been under the belief that all Unix redirection operators wait until all the output/input is ready and _then_ move it along, i.e. buffer it all until the sending program/file is done. Thus I wouldn't expect the `|` in Sean's command here to send anything along to `grep` until `tail` is done spitting out lines, which of course with the `-f` flag it won't ever do until it is interrupted. (I'm not at a *nix box to try this out, though, otherwise I would have just tested it instead of asking.)

Comment: It works, I use it lots; most of the time to track mail for whiney users.  `tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep -i "whineyUser@myDomain.com"`

Comment: @Kromey, depends on the command after the pipe. If it is `sort` or `wc` it will wait the `end-of-file` to start sorting, if it is `grep` or `sed`  or another line processing command, it will process input every `end-of-line`, which is the default character for flushing the i/o stream buffer.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Another useful tool to add to my belt! :-)

Answer (score 0):

use named pipe like this:

Let us assume we want to read file `logfile.txt` continuously and execute code, that we store in `readfile.sh`.

```bash
# readfile.sh

while read line
do
  echo $line
done < mypipe
```

```bash
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ #this will block (will not exit)
$ ./readfile.sh
```

In another shell, but the same directory (where file mypipe is located):

```bash
$ # This will go to background
$ tail -f logfile.txt >> mypipe &
```

Done. Whatever keeps coming into logfile.txt will get printed via `readfile.sh` which didn't exit.